# Twilio Conversations Client create() not returning Promise

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, twilio, redux-thunk

I'm trying to instantiate a Twilio Conversation client within my redux-thunk. The client never returns the Promise upon creation.

I've tried this in demo application where instead of using thunks it's simply using app context / provider (ref https://github.com/Gapur/react-native-twilio-chat) and it works fine.

twilio-service.js

```
import {Client} from '@twilio/conversations';
...
export class TwilioService {
  static serviceInstance;
  static chatClient;

  ...

  async getChatClient(twilioToken) {
    console.log('TwilioService::getChatClient::', twilioToken);
    if (!TwilioService.chatClient && !twilioToken) {
      throw new Error('Twilio token is null or undefined');
    }
    if (!TwilioService.chatClient && twilioToken) {
      return Client.create(twilioToken, {logLevel: 'debug'}).then((client) => {
        console.log('TwilioService::getChatClient::client', client);
        TwilioService.chatClient = client;
        this.addConnectionStateListener();
        return TwilioService.chatClient;
      });
    }
    return Promise.resolve().then(() => TwilioService.chatClient);
  }

}
```

clientAction.js

```
import {TwilioService} from './twilio-service';
...

export const initChatSDK = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch(clientInitRequest);

  getToken(getState().auth.user.identity)
    .then((res) => TwilioService.getInstance().getChatClient(res.jwt))
    .then(() => TwilioService.getInstance().addTokenListener(getToken));
};

...
```

iOS - Client logLevel: 'debug' output

```
logger.js:21 2021-08-11T10:43:11.305Z Twilsock T: resetBackoff
logger.js:21 2021-08-11T10:43:11.306Z Twilsock T: finalizeSocket
logger.js:21 2021-08-11T10:43:11.306Z Twilsock T: closing socket
logger.js:19 2021-08-11T10:43:11.312Z Notifications T: Persisting registration Set(1) {"token"} RegistrationState {token: "[REMOVE_TOKEN]", notificationId: "", messageTypes: Set(0)}
logger.js:19 2021-08-11T10:43:11.313Z Notifications T: Persisting registration Set(1) {"token"} RegistrationState {token: "[REMOVE_TOKEN]", notificationId: "", messageTypes: Set(0)}
logger.js:19 2021-08-11T10:43:11.314Z Notifications T: Persisting registration Set(1) {"token"} RegistrationState {token: "[REMOVE_TOKEN]", notificationId: "", messageTypes: Set(0)}
logger.js:21 2021-08-11T10:43:11.318Z Twilsock T: connect
logger.js:22 2021-08-11T10:43:11.318Z Twilsock D: FSM: userConnect: disconnected --> connecting
logger.js:21 2021-08-11T10:43:11.319Z Twilsock T: setupSocket: [REMOVED_TOKEN}
logger.js:22 2021-08-11T10:43:11.320Z Twilsock D: Adding starting timepoint for 'twilsock.sdk.connect' event
logger.js:21 2021-08-11T10:43:11.321Z Twilsock T: connecting to socket
logger.js:19 2021-08-11T10:43:11.323Z Notifications T: Add subscriptions for message type:  twilio.sync.event twilsock
logger.js:19 2021-08-11T10:43:11.324Z Notifications T: Persisting registration Set(1) {"messageType"} RegistrationState {token: "", notificationId: "", messageTypes: Set(1)}
logger.js:19 2021-08-11T10:43:11.326Z Notifications T: Add subscriptions for message type:  com.twilio.rtd.cds.document twilsock
logger.js:19 2021-08-11T10:43:11.327Z Notifications T: One registration attempt is already in progress
logger.js:19 2021-08-11T10:43:11.327Z Notifications T: Add subscriptions for message type:  com.twilio.rtd.cds.list twilsock
logger.js:19 2021-08-11T10:43:11.328Z Notifications T: One registration attempt is already in progress
logger.js:19 2021-08-11T10:43:11.329Z Notifications T: Add subscriptions for message type:  com.twilio.rtd.cds.map twilsock
logger.js:19 2021-08-11T10:43:11.329Z Notifications T: One registration attempt is already in progress
logger.js:22 2021-08-11T10:43:11.338Z Twilsock D: Adding starting timepoint for 'conversations.client.startup' event
logger.js:22 2021-08-11T10:43:11.360Z Twilsock D: Emitting stateChanged("connecting")
RCTLog.js:47 SocketRocket: In debug mode.  Allowing connection to any root cert
logger.js:22 2021-08-11T10:43:13.168Z Twilsock D: socket opened wss://tsock.us1.twilio.com/v3/wsconnect
logger.js:22 2021-08-11T10:43:13.169Z Twilsock D: FSM: socketConnected: connecting --> initialising
logger.js:21 2021-08-11T10:43:13.169Z Twilsock T: sendInit
logger.js:22 2021-08-11T10:43:13.170Z Twilsock D: Adding starting timepoint for 'twilsock.sdk.init' event
logger.js:21 2021-08-11T10:43:13.171Z Twilsock T: sendInit
logger.js:22 2021-08-11T10:43:13.174Z Twilsock D: send request: TWILSOCK V3.0 869
{"id":"TM26a39241-aba8-4c94-8eb4-82e4f43ca52a","method":"init","token":"[REMOVED_TOKEN}","continuation_token":null,"metadata":{"ver":"0.6.2","env":"Chrome Mobile","envv":"91.0.4472.124","os":"Android","osv":"6.0","osa":32,"type":"conversations","sdk":"JS","sdkv":"1.2.3"},"registrations":null,"tweaks":null,"capabilities":["client_update","offline_storage","telemetry.v1"],"payload_size":0}

logger.js:22 2021-08-11T10:43:13.266Z Twilsock D: message received:  reply
logger.js:21 2021-08-11T10:43:13.266Z Twilsock T: message received:  {method: "reply", id: "TM26a39241-aba8-4c94-8eb4-82e4f43ca52a", payload_size: 0, status: {…}, capabilities: Array(2), …}
logger.js:22 2021-08-11T10:43:43.356Z Twilsock D: message received:  ping
logger.js:21 2021-08-11T10:43:43.357Z Twilsock T: message received:  {method: "ping", id: "TMb74a665d3ea34a899fea8dc1a5aa64fc", payload_size: 0}
logger.js:21 2021-08-11T10:43:43.357Z Twilsock T: confirmReceiving
logger.js:22 2021-08-11T10:43:43.357Z Twilsock D: send request: TWILSOCK V3.0 147
{"id":"TMb74a665d3ea34a899fea8dc1a5aa64fc","method":"reply","payload_type":"application/json","status":{"code":200,"status":"OK"},"payload_size":0}

logger.js:22 2021-08-11T10:44:13.464Z Twilsock D: message received:  ping
logger.js:21 2021-08-11T10:44:13.465Z Twilsock T: message received:  {method: "ping", id: "TM4552380bc9784dc9b35855651ab4f6fe", payload_size: 0}
logger.js:21 2021-08-11T10:44:13.465Z Twilsock T: confirmReceiving
logger.js:22 2021-08-11T10:44:13.465Z Twilsock D: send request: TWILSOCK V3.0 147
{"id":"TM4552380bc9784dc9b35855651ab4f6fe","method":"reply","payload_type":"application/json","status":{"code":200,"status":"OK"},"payload_size":0}

logger.js:22 2021-08-11T10:44:43.570Z Twilsock D: message received:  ping
logger.js:21 2021-08-11T10:44:43.570Z Twilsock T: message received:  {method: "ping", id: "TM53d7963c6f1b4401a8a76dc095c30ea2", payload_size: 0}
logger.js:21 2021-08-11T10:44:43.572Z Twilsock T: confirmReceiving
logger.js:22 2021-08-11T10:44:43.572Z Twilsock D: send request: TWILSOCK V3.0 147
{"id":"TM53d7963c6f1b4401a8a76dc095c30ea2","method":"reply","payload_type":"application/json","status":{"code":200,"status":"OK"},"payload_size":0}

logger.js:22 2021-08-11T10:45:13.677Z Twilsock D: message received:  ping
logger.js:21 2021-08-11T10:45:13.677Z Twilsock T: message received:  {method: "ping", id: "TMc9d23796983645b3bbe8c98ca9ed63af", payload_size: 0}
logger.js:21 2021-08-11T10:45:13.680Z Twilsock T: confirmReceiving
logger.js:22 2021-08-11T10:45:13.680Z Twilsock D: send request: TWILSOCK V3.0 147
{"id":"TMc9d23796983645b3bbe8c98ca9ed63af","method":"reply","payload_type":"application/json","status":{"code":200,"status":"OK"},"payload_size":0}

logger.js:22 2021-08-11T10:45:43.783Z Twilsock D: message received:  ping
logger.js:21 2021-08-11T10:45:43.783Z Twilsock T: message received:  {method: "ping", id: "TM5dd970724b444920b4712354f05f6b19", payload_size: 0}
logger.js:21 2021-08-11T10:45:43.785Z Twilsock T: confirmReceiving
logger.js:22 2021-08-11T10:45:43.785Z Twilsock D: send request: TWILSOCK V3.0 147
{"id":"TM5dd970724b444920b4712354f05f6b19","method":"reply","payload_type":"application/json","status":{"code":200,"status":"OK"},"payload_size":0}
```

Is there a reason it doesn't work via redux-thunk or saga leveraging the same service class?

Comment: Not sure with redux-thunk but worked perfectly with react hooks

Comment: Are you seeing any logs from the client as it is being created?

Comment: @philnash debug log added

Comment: @RajendranNadar the goal here is to maintain the React/Redux Web Socket Flow